# Cycle through open windows in gnome3 workspace without minimizing

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

Is it possible to cycle through open windows on a specific gnome3 workspace while showing the windows in their original size, similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> in MS Windows?

I'm aware of the window picker (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and the desktop view (***Super***), but that's not what I'm after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> works in GNOME 3 too. It [cycles windows on the current workspace](https://gist.github.com/rothgar/7079722).

If it's disabled by any chance you should be able to enable it from the "**Switch windows directly**" option in *Settings* > *Keyboard shortcuts* > *Navigation*.

Unfortunately, this may not work properly with older GNOME versions. It cycles through all the open windows in GNOME v3.26 and v3.28, but switches back and forth between current and last windows in v3.18.

Comment: It switches back and forth between current and last windows, that's not cycling through workspace windows.

Comment: @BaselShishani What's your GNOME version? Probably it's possible only with newer ones. Just checked "cycles" in 3.26 and 3.28, but "switches back and forth" as you've mentioned in an older 3.18.

Comment: Mine is the older 3.18, will have to upgrade for this 'feature'. Thx for for the help.